# matplotlib how to correctly plot text in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

This image is plot using:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
hist(...)
subplot(1,2,2)
text(...)
```

But I don't want the border of second plot and I want the text on the upper left of the plot. How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
hist(...)
ax2 = subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
for spine in ax2.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
ax2.invert_yaxis()
ax2.text(..., verticalalignment="top")
```

Update:

As pointed out in the comments, you can also just do:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
hist(...)
ax2 = subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.axis("off")
ax2.invert_yaxis()
ax2.text(..., verticalalignment="top")
```

Although this will remove the default axis background too (depending on your settings and Matplotlib version, this may leave you with a gray background color).

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: For this, you can just use `plt.axis('off')` on the second plot.

Comment: Yes, I checked the Axes API, and replace it with `ax2.set_axis_off()`

Comment: why do you `invert_yaxis()`?

Comment: @tom So the text will appear on the upper part of the plot, as requested by the OP (seems that the origin, or a point close to it, is being used as coordinates for the text).

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just use the `x, y` coordinates in `ax.text()` to set the position of the text? and if needed set `transform=ax2.transAxes`?

Comment: @tom You could do that, but I wouldn't say it's simpler... You'd need to retrieve the maximum value of the Y axis and use it as coordinate, and if the axis ever changes scale for whatever reason it may cause the text to move. I think it's easier to think of it in terms of a canvas having the origin in the top-left corner. But I guess you can find pros and cons depending on the specific case and personal preference.

Comment: That's why you would set the transform to axes coordinates rather than data coordinate. But each to his own, I guess :)

Comment: @tom Ahh alright I see what you mean, yes well there are many ways to go about it I guess.